# Error: Javascript reading XML page when apostrophe in URL

Tags: javascript, xml, apostrophe

I have the URL:
http://website.com/xml_searchresults.php?cityID=1&type=1&searchTerm=Mark\'s Sports Bar&showOpenOnly=0

I generate it in PHP and then send it to Javascript:

```
var searchURL = "<?php echo $searchURL; ?>";
```

I'm using Javascript for Google Maps but my maps can't read the XML file when there's an apostrophe in the URL string. I don't want to remove it because the XML file looks for a perfect match in my database when doing a search ranking. I've been able to work around it in the PHP no problem, but my maps are killing me.

I don't know a whole lot about the intracracies of Javascript but I'm convinced the blank maps come from errors when an apostrophe  is present.

Comment: What happens if you urlencode ``$searchURL`` in your PHP script?

Comment: The apostrophe isn't the problem - looks like the slash is. Remove it and add it later

Comment: @Kippie - urlencode didn't seem to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chen Asraf

Both the apostrophe and the slash were causing problems so like you said I removed them and added them back later as seen here:
[PHP function for removing and adding back in \'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329313/php-function-for-removing-and-adding-back-in)