# PHP function for removing and adding back in \'?

Tags: php, string, function

I have a search form for finding restaurants. I got it handling apostrophe's just fine for the actual search, but when they're passed as \' into Javascript for mapping it's killing my maps.

Example:
xml_searchresults.php?cityID=1&type=1&searchTerm=Sonny\'s Real Bit BBQ

For a simple fix, in PHP I'm trying to go from:

`$searchTerm = "Sonny\'s Real Bit BBQ"` (in the original PHP file)

Then replace the \' with [slashapostrophe]:

`$searchTerm = "Sonny[slashapostrophe]s Real Bit BBQ"` (to be fed to javascript)

and then replace the [slashapostrophe] back with \':

`$searchTerm = "Sonny\'s Real Bit BBQ"` (in the PHP generated XML map marker file)

I tried str_replace but the quotes and slashes confuse it. Thanks!

Comment: You can just strip the slashes and put the result in a different variable, you don't need to add the slashes back again after.

Comment: have you tried stripslashes()?

Comment: You should never have escape sequences in your actual values to begin with, they're all just transport encodings. Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php function addslashes() to quote string with '\' and stripslashes() to remove extra '\' symbols ( to unquote quoted string)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use the two functions to accomplish what I needed.

`$searchTerm = "Sonny\'s Real Bit BBQ";
echo $searchTerm;`
`$searchTerm2 = stripslashes($searchTerm);
echo $searchTerm2;`

`$searchTerm3 = str_replace("'", "[sapos]", $searchTerm2);
echo $searchTerm3;`

`$searchTerm4 = str_replace("[sapos]", "'", $searchTerm3);
echo $searchTerm4;`

`$searchTerm5 = addslashes($searchTerm4);
echo $searchTerm5;`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for stripslashes(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php